# ZF2 multiple forms on the same page,ajax

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework2

I have two forms on the same view script in zf2 application.The one is
a comment form which is submitted by ajax and other is submitted
normally. I have completely different submit names and values. So no
Conflict upto this level. The ajax form works fine but when i tried
to submit the another form it gives me an application error.

After when I refresh this page it shows the posted data and take me to
the proper action.

Now my question is what can generate application error when the post is submitted ?

```
2014-01-08T17:17:23+00:00 DEBUG (7): Zend_Session::start() - library/Zend/Session.php(Line:480): Error #2 Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer Array
#0 /library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php(143): Zend_Session::start(true)
#1 /app/controllers/VisawizardController.php(37): Zend_Session_Namespace-__construct('VisawizardContr...')
#2 /library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(133): VisawizardController->init()
#3 /library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(262): Zend_Controller_Action->__construct(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http), Array)
#4 /library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#5 /library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(77): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#6 /library/Zend/Application.php(358): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#7 forms/index.php(45): Zend_Application->run()
```

Comment: What does the error show you?

Comment: this is the error type from the errorController :EXCEPTION_OTHER